# Help with compiling error

Tags: command-line, compiling

I already compiled I already compiled libfreenect for natty and now I am trying to install kinect mouse: https://github.com/Ooblik/Kinect-Mouse/
But when I type `make` I receive an error...

This is the terminal:

```
eric@eric-desktop:~$ cd /home/eric/kinect_mouse
eric@eric-desktop:~/kinect_mouse$ mkdir build
eric@eric-desktop:~/kinect_mouse$ cd build
eric@eric-desktop:~/kinect_mouse/build$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Looking for include files CMAKE_HAVE_PTHREAD_H
-- Looking for include files CMAKE_HAVE_PTHREAD_H - found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE 
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so - found
-- Looking for gethostbyname
-- Looking for gethostbyname - found
-- Looking for connect
-- Looking for connect - found
-- Looking for remove
-- Looking for remove - found
-- Looking for shmat
-- Looking for shmat - found
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE - found
-- Found X11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/eric/kinect_mouse/build
eric@eric-desktop:~/kinect_mouse/build$ make
Scanning dependencies of target kmouse
[100%] Building C object CMakeFiles/kmouse.dir/kinect_mouse.c.o
Linking C executable kmouse
CMakeFiles/kmouse.dir/kinect_mouse.c.o: In function `freenect_threadfunc':
kinect_mouse.c:(.text+0xd6d): undefined reference to `freenect_set_video_format'
kinect_mouse.c:(.text+0xd81): undefined reference to `freenect_set_depth_format'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [kmouse] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/kmouse.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
eric@eric-desktop:~/kinect_mouse/build$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error indicates a missing library. Doing a `grep -rn freenect_set_video_format .` in the directory containing `libfreenect` revealed that [`fakenect/fakenect.c`](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/blob/master/fakenect/fakenect.c) contained the required function. Reading the [fakenect/README](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/blob/master/fakenect/README) made clear that you need to link against that library when building `kinect_mouse`.

So, edit `kinect_mouse/CMakeLists.txt` and put `link_directories(/usr/local/lib64/fakenect)` in it:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

link_directories(/usr/local/lib64/fakenect)

add_executable(kmouse kinect_mouse.c)
```

Clear your build directory and build again.

Comment: Thanks that worked but when I run kinect_mouse I get another error:

Error: Environmental variable FAKENECT_PATH is not set.  Set it to a path that was created using the 'record' utility.

Comment: Looks like you need to run the `record` program too which is provided by libkinect too. Please read https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/blob/master/fakenect/README